# Isekai Manga: main character's level looks low but is high and is abandoned

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai

I read a manga a while back about the main character being reincarnated into another world. He’s born into royalty, and is excited, but when they look at his level they’re in shock. His level looks super low (like level 1 or 2), but his level is actually so high that only the last number is shown (it’s a level in the thousands I think), but nobody realizes this.

They can’t handle such a weak person being the “crown prince”, so they abandon him in the woods. Then somebody finds him and raises him with others.

I remember all of this about the manga, but I just can’t seem to remember the title?

Comment: Could it be Suterare Yuusha wa Kitakuchuu? https://myanimelist.net/manga/116890/Suterare_Yuusha_wa_Kitakuchuu

Comment: https://www.novelupdates.com/series/the-discarded-hero-wants-to-return-home/ has a better summary.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots yup, it points better to the question and I really can't think of any other manga that has this setting.

Comment: @RigaCrypto Why not make that an answer? :)

Comment: @FuzzyBoots Cause it apparently it wasn't the one :)

Comment: @rigacrypto: Hmm... partial answers are valid too, but I understand that there's no Prince involved.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think you are looking for [*Jitsu wa Ore, Saikyou deshita?*](https://www.novelupdates.com/series/jitsu-wa-ore-saikyou-deshitatensei-chokugo-wa-donzoko-sutato-demo-banno-maho-de-gyakuten-jinsei-o-josho-chu/), also known as *Am I Actually the Strongest?*.

> I, a HIKKI-NEET, suddenly reincarnated in another world as a prince, and was immediately deemed the weakest ever, with my life already in a pinch after being abandoned as a baby, being stared down by a huge beast!?
>
> However, I could only use one kind of magic. It was close, but I was able to avoid a “dead end” in my first few days of being born using that magic.
>
> Anyways, I just want to live a lazy shut-in life as an adopted noble with my one all-purpose magic, but…?

The main character gets a power level of 1002 (actually high power) from the goddess but it only shows up as 02, since the power level indicator only displays the last two digits. He reincarnates as the crown prince, but his power level leads him to getting disowned. He gets picked up by a wolf girl (somebody finds him) before being retrieved by the guard commander and now he lives with the guard commander's family with a wolf girl maid (being raised by others).

Comment: Yes!! Thank you so much, I’ve been looking for this forever :))))

Answer (score -1):

I think you are referring to a manga called: am I actually the strongest?

https://www.mgeko.com/manga/am-i-actually-the-strongest/all-chapters/

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  This is already posted as the accepted answer; please don't post duplicate answers.